# Convert .xls files from .msg attachments wihtout storing .xls as temporary files on disk

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to extract all .xls attachment files from .msg files and then convert them to .xlsx
So my current code flow looks like this:

```
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(mesg_path, file))
att=msg.Attachments
for i in att:
    if i.FileName.endswith('.xls'):
        i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join('C:/some_path_goes_here', i.FileName))
```

and then I use some other code to open these .xls files and convert to .xlsx files:

```
for file in dir_list:
if file.endswith('.xls'):
    file_with_destination = os.path.join(destination_path, file)
    file_with_path = os.path.join(source_path, file)
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_with_path)
    wb.SaveAs(file_with_destination + "x", FileFormat = 51)    
    wb.Close(True)                                        
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

It does the job. But I am curious if I could convert .xls files strait when extracting them from .msg attachments so I don't have to create temp .xls file and store it on disk. Is there any way to do it something like that: ?

```
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(mesg_path, file))
    att=msg.Attachments
    for i in att:
       if i.FileName.endswith('.xls'):
       #i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join('C:/some_path_goes_here', i.FileName))
       #instead of saving convert to .xlsx and save to destination folder
```

Comment: No.  Excel needs to open a file.

Comment: Can you share a sample msg attachment file containing xls file ?

Comment: Check out the answer you can save the file without temporarily storing in on disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly read and save the file into `xlsx format` at desired location as mentioned in below code. Just update the `file_destination` variable as to the desitnation path where you want to save the file.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(mesg_path, file))
att=msg.Attachments
for i in att:
    if i.FileName.endswith('.xls'):
        file_content_bytes = i.content
        my_file_io = io.BytesIO(file_content_bytes)
        # Below goes your file name or the destination path
        file_destination = "filename.xlsx"
        pd.read_excel(io=my_file_io).to_excel(file_destination, index=False)
```